# Can't see parameters in CCDT file

Tags: websphere, ibm-mq

I'm using ccdt for connection factory in WAS. I can't see the host, port and etc. in WAS console. May be I can install some plugin for possibility to see parameters in .tab file?

Answer (score 2):

Yes! The plugin is called IBM MQ Client.  Just use the `runmqsc` command with the -n option as described in the Knowledge Center's [`runmqsc` page](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_9.0.0/com.ibm.mq.ref.adm.doc/q083460_.htm).  You can download the IBM MQ Client from the [SupportPacs page](http://ibm.co/SupptPacs).  Look for SupportPacs named MQC*.  MQC8 is the v8 client, MQC9 is the v9 client, etc.  Also, hover over the [ibm-mq](/questions/tagged/ibm-mq) tag and click "info" for an extensive compilation of "getting started" material, including the Knowledge Centers and links to the SupportPacs.